# How to setup layout constraints for a horizontal alignment of UIImageView's

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, alignment

I am trying to implement something like the image shown (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKmGO.png) below using auto layout in Swift, but every time I end up with some issues. Can anyone please tell me the best way to implement auto layout for this kind of arrangement in horizontal grid for 3,4,5 or more image views.

Comment: why don't you use collectionview?

Comment: are you interested in horizontal arrangement only?

Comment: If you are developing for iOS9+ only, consider using UIStackView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps
1) first select all of them and add constraint EQUAL WIDTH to images
2) set the leading space between left margin and first image view( let it be d)
3) Similarly set trailing space between the right margin and last imageview (let it be d) 
4) Now add constraint HORIZONTAL DISTANCE(d) between all the image view e.g.

**LEFT MARGIN-d-IMAGE1-d-IMAGE2-d-IMAGE3-d-IMAGE4-d-RIGHT MARGIN**

Checkout Stanford Cs193p lecture no 8. Something similar is considered which was a basic calculator with equal width and height of keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below (for horizontal arrangement)

```
var arrayOfImages = [image1,image2,image3,image4]
var previousImage:UIView? = nil
let horizontalSpaceBetweenImages = 20.0
let viewToUse = self.view //change this view to the one in which you are adding images as subviews

for image in arrayOfImages {
    viewToUse.addSubview(image)
    if previousItem == nil {
        // this is the first item
        viewToUse.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewToUse, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: image, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    }
    else {
        viewToUse.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: previousImage, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: horizontalSpaceBetweenImages))
        viewToUse.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: previousImage, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    }
    previousImage = image
}

// now add trailing constraint for last image
viewToUse.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: arrayOfImages.last, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewToUse, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

this code sorts out horizontal alignment. It should be trivial to then add vertical alignment constraints (they should be easier to implement)

Answer (score 0):

A collectionView would be the best option for you if you are going to be switching between 3, 4, and 5 images in your view. If you are, however, trying to have a set number of images displaying (number of UIImages stays the same) You can try doing this method:

Everything here is going to be based on the horizontal distance available to you based on the device size. So to start, you need to figure out what height you'll want for the images. Do the heights need to be relative to the width? Or can the heights for each image stay the same?

If the heights need to stay relative to the widths, put an "Aspect Ratio" constraint on each image. If the heights can stay static, place a "height constraint" on each image.

Next you need to set constraints for the distances between the images.

At this point you are still going to have errors because the width for each image will be ambiguous. To fix this, select all the images simultaneously and then add the constraint "Equal Widths." As long as you've made sure that the images are pinned to the top, you should no longer have auto-layout issues at this point.

Let me know if I can be more clear on any of these steps.